# How to analyse chord progression

Tags: chord-progressions

Hello this is my first question, i am new for music learning and i am practicing the song "close to you" by the carpenters
and i'm wonder how is the composer choose these chords and what these chords function are, for example at verse "C-Bsus4-B7-Bm-Em-C-G" how's B7 and Bm chord come from?
And where should I start to learn to learn about this topic, what is this topic called, what are the books's name.
Thanks you in advance for any help.

Comment: Richard Carpenter talks about this in one of the Carpenters films, sorry, don't know which, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for harmonic analysis.

You can find most of the chords you mentioned in the G Mayor scale.
How can you tell? You have a minor chord (Bm or III grade of G mayor) a half tone below a mayor chord (C or IV grade of G mayor).
Bsus4 is just the III grade with an E (which already exists in the scale).

The one chord that escapes G mayor is B7 which tells us that the song modulated into a minor scale (better explained on the books :))

Any decent music theory book can help you understand scales and their chord structures.
I personally liked  Mark Levine's Jazz theory.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, because your question is fairly open ended.

In terms of theory, the progression is in Em, thus B is the dominant chord. Bsus4 maintains the E from the preceding C chord, B7 is the true dominant seventh and Bm is the minor dominant chord ('softening' the resolution), resolving to Em.